# sum column in visual basic 2015 report

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Public Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= invo.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123456;")



    Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'print the items balance
        Try
            'Dim NO As String = Val(txtBillNo.Text)
            Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT itemname, Sum(quntity)  as quntity FROM temp_bal GROUP BY temp_bal.itemname;", Con)
            DA.Fill(Form4.DataSet2, "datatable1")
            Form4.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

I want to sum the total in the reprt but iI can't I tried this `Sum(Fields!quntity.Value)` but I get error I am using vb 2015 can any one help

Comment: Why in the report when you can do it from the database call? Also a quick Google search for exactly what you need. Please [**see**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/sum-of-a-column-values-in-reports-automatically-using-expres/) this.

Comment: Thank you, but I've got a table, for example, as a result of more than a query and I want to get the total rows in the report

Comment: Get all of values and sum all of them together.

Comment: can you give me example